# Gas turns into a vapour liquid mixture when it is adiabatically expands

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, states-of-matter, adiabatic

Why does gas turn into a vapour liquid mixture when it is adiabatically expanded in a refrigerator?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the gas in question, and the location in that gas' phase diagram. You are decreasing pressure, but you are also decreasing the temperature. Depending on where you start in the phase diagram, some gases may end up in a mixed state. See the [Wikipedia article on phase diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram). Below is an example of a $T$-$s$ diagram for steam. The region marked "saturated vapor" is the one where you have both gaseous and liquid states.

[image]